# Time difference in hours and seconds over a partition window in Teradata (Sessionizing Records)

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

Given a table like this:

```
cust_id                time
    123 2015-01-01 12:15:05
    123 2015-01-01 12:17:06
    123 2015-01-02 13:15:08
    123 2015-01-02 15:15:10
    456 2015-01-01 10:15:05
    456 2015-01-01 12:15:07
    456 2015-01-01 14:11:10
```

I would like to calculate the time difference between each preceding record (think `lag` function) by `cust_id`. My desired output:

```
cust_id                time diff_hours  diff_seconds
    123 2015-01-01 12:15:05       NULL          NULL
    123 2015-01-01 12:17:06       0.00           121
    123 2015-01-02 13:15:08       1.04         89882
    123 2015-01-02 15:15:10       0.08          7202
    456 2015-01-01 10:15:05       NULL          NULL
    456 2015-01-01 12:15:07       0.08          7202 
    456 2015-01-01 14:11:10       0.08          6963
```

How do I accomplish this in Teradata?

I have tried stuff like:

```
SELECT
  *
  , (time - time) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM
  table_01
```

However, while the `NULL`s show up where expected, I keep receive `0.0` for all other results. I have also tried using wrapping `(time - time)` with `SUM` and I have tried using `EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIME)` and a few other variants -- e.g., trying to place `DAY(4) to SECOND`, but I can't seem to get the syntax/ordering/conversion quite right, especially when tossing a window function into the mix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `LAG` in Teradata, but you can rewrite it:

```
SELECT
  t.*
  , (time)
    - min(time) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id 
            ORDER BY time
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) SECOND(4)
FROM
  table_01 as t
```

When you try to get seconds you will encouter "Interval Overflow" errors, i.e. more than 9999 seconds. Either change to `DAY(4) TO SECOND` or use this SQL UDF I wrote a few years ago for calculating the difference of two timestamps in seconds:

```
REPLACE FUNCTION TimeStamp_Diff_Seconds
(
   ts1 TIMESTAMP(6)
  ,ts2 TIMESTAMP(6)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,6)
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN
(CAST((CAST(ts2 AS DATE)- CAST(ts1 AS DATE)) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) * 60*60*24)
      + ((EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM ts2) - EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM ts1)) * 60*60)
      + ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts2) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts1)) * 60)
      +  (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts2) - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts1))
;
```

Comment: Thanks `dnoeth` -- can you expand the explanation to help me understand when I would use `1 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW` vs. `1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`? In addition, why the need for `min` and wrapping the first `time` in parentheses?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns: `wrapping the first time in parentheses?`, you donÄ't need it, it's a leftover from your query. The `MIN` could be `MAX` also, it's just to get one value. When you use `CURRENT ROW` it's not the same result for the 1st row, just try it.

Comment: Will do - what would you recommend for creating the two columns, `diff_hours` and `diff_second` -- using `EXTRACT` or would you use some variant of `DAY(4) to SECOND`?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns: Just added to my answer :-)

Comment: And for one final bonus point/clarity, `DAY(4) to SECOND` will work provided that there is no more than 9,999 days between the timestamps; otherwise, just use the impervious UDF?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns: Yep, Teradata supports only up to 4 digits for intervals, stupid, isn't it?