# Timestamp difference in seconds between consecutive rows

Tags: teradata, difference

I have a data set that looks like:

```
Trans_ID       Time_Stamp               Emp_ID
1111           9/15/16 01:12:50         9999
1112           9/15/16 01:12:59         9999
1113           9/15/16 01:13:01         9999
```

I need to get the difference (in seconds) between the current row and the row before it.

I'm looking for something like:

```
Trans_ID       Time_Stamp               Emp_ID       Diff
1111           9/15/16 01:12:50         9999
1112           9/15/16 01:12:59         9999         9
1113           9/15/16 01:13:01         9999         2
```

The format can be flexible, but I mostly just need it to be calculated in some way.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35633254

Comment: Thanks!  I actually got exactly what I needed from that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time difference in hours and seconds over a partition window in Teradata (Sessionizing Records)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633152/time-difference-in-hours-and-seconds-over-a-partition-window-in-teradata-sessio)