# Teradata - timestamp difference - interval filed overflow error

Tags: teradata

I am trying to subtract two TIMESTAMP filed and want to get the difference in minute.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ( CAST(END_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) - CAST(START_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) MINUTE(4) TO SECOND)) + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (CAST(END_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) - CAST(START_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) MINUTE(4) TO SECOND)) * 1.00 / 60 
from tableA
```

But I am getting interval filed overflow error.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35633254, you can either modify the logic or divide by 60.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve the solution using below

```
(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIME_DIFF) * 60) + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIME_DIFF) + (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIME_DIFF) * 1.00 / 60)
```

where **TIME_DIFF** is `(ACTL_END_DT - ACTL_START_DT) DAY(4) TO SECOND`